# Fortify Cross Site Scripting: Poor Validation

Tags: jsp, jstl, xss, fortify

I have used JSTL  tag to fix the XSS vulnerability issue Fortify reported on my JSP's. But After using  though the XSS vulnerability issue was resolved, it resulted in a new issue as 'XSS: Poor Validation'. What are the other possible solutions I could implement to resove this poor validation issue?

Fortify suggests HTML/ XML/ URL encoding is not a good practise as the code will be decoded during runtime, which could still result in the XSS attack.

I am using struts framework injected with spring. I have fields where user can provide input as well as fields that are read from the database. I ve searched for possible solutions but havent had any luck in finding one yet.

Thanks,
Deena

Comment: Use OWASP Encoder Jar. Fortify resolved my Cross Site Scripting Issues.

Download the jar from the following URL. Second Tab has examples. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project

Answer (score -1):

Use the proper encoding based on where you're outputting data.  Specifics can be found [OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) - along with information about OWASP's `AntiSamy` and `Java HTML Sanitizer`.

Additionally, [white listing](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet) can be employed where appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

Use OWASP Encoder Jar. Fortify resolved my Cross Site Scripting Issues.

Download the jar from the following URL. Second Tab has examples.
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project

Snippet:

```
<body><%= Encode.forHtml(UNTRUSTED) %></body>
```

http://owasp.github.io/owasp-java-encoder/encoder/apidocs/index.html?index-all.html